# Sub menu with MvcSiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

Currently i'm using the MvcSiteMapProvider to provide my sitemap. I'm now converting my menu to use the same XML. I have created a MyMenu.cshtml with the following code

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.MenuHelperModel
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) { 
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => node)</li>
        }
    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

And i display it with

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu("MyMenu")
```

I'm trying to get nested menus to work. As i have some dropdown menu items that havesub catergories. For example

> --Main Menu
>
> ------Sub Menu

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The menu templates are broken up into 3 separate parts, so you will need to override each part  (not just the main one) by specifying the additional templates inside of your custom one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767401/mvcsitemap-generating-a-menu-without-messing-the-breadcumbs/21788852#21788852) for a set of templates to get you started. Then it is just a matter of modifying the HTML the way you would like.